# AS is not valid ate this postition expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can you, please help me. I am trying to create a procedure but is says error, to AS. This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_login
( flag int ,
uid varchar(50), 
fname varchar(50), 
lname varchar(50),
email varchar(50), 
address varchar(50),
city varchar(50),
country varchar(50),
phonenumber varchar(50),
 gender char(10),
 dob varchar(50),
 photo varchar(50), 
 secques varchar(50),
 secans varchar(50), 
 pswd varchar(50), 
 utype char(10),
 status bit)
AS 

BEGIN
if(@flag=0)
SELECT userid from Login where userid=@uid
END
```

What can it be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is valif for Function but not procedure and the if Then ENDif mus be complete

the select needs also needs a semicolon at the end

And @uid and uid are not the same

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  sp_login
( flag int ,
uid varchar(50), 
fname varchar(50), 
lname varchar(50),
email varchar(50), 
address varchar(50),
city varchar(50),
country varchar(50),
phonenumber varchar(50),
 gender char(10),
 dob varchar(50),
 photo varchar(50), 
 secques varchar(50),
 secans varchar(50), 
 pswd varchar(50), 
 utype char(10),
 status bit)


BEGIN
IF (flag=0) THEN
    SELECT userid from Login where userid=uid;
END IF;
END
```